# Why the neural network is not learning?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am training a neural network with a simple dataset. I have tried different combinations of parameters, optimizers, learning rates ... but even after 20 epochs the network is still not learning anything.

I wonder where in the following code lies the problem?

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import  Sequential, load_model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Flatten
from tensorflow import keras
from livelossplot import PlotLossesKeras
from keras.models import Model
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import pandas as pd


seed = 42

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=100000, n_features=2, n_redundant=0, 
                           n_informative=2, random_state=seed)

print(f"Number of features: {X.shape[1]}")
print(f"Number of samples: {X.shape[0]}")


df = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate((X,y.reshape(-1,1)), axis=1))
df.set_axis([*df.columns[:-1], 'Class'], axis=1, inplace=True)

df['Class'] = df['Class'].astype('int')
X = df.drop('Class', axis=1)
y = df['Class']

X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

print(f"Train set: {X_train.shape}")
print(f"Validation set: {X_val.shape}")


scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_train.astype(np.float64))
X_val_scaled = scaler.transform(X_val.astype(np.float64))

inputs = Input(shape=X_train_scaled.shape[1:])
h0 = Dense(5, activation='relu')(inputs)
h1 = Dense(5, activation='relu')(h0)
preds = Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(h1)

model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=preds)
opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001)
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=20, verbose=0,
                    validation_data=(X_val_scaled, y_val),
                    callbacks=[PlotLossesKeras()]) 

score_train = model.evaluate(X_train_scaled, y_train, verbose=0)
score_test = model.evaluate(X_val_scaled, y_val, verbose=0) 
print('Train score:', score_train[0])
print('Train accuracy:', score_train[1])
print('Test score:', score_test[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score_test[1])
```

The code produces the following kind of output

[image]

Comment: Are you able to provide a reproducible code snippet? Please see, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: please provide data samples

Comment: @User1010 do you mean Stack Snippets? in the documentation only talks of HTML, JavaScript, or CSS not python. I'm not sure about what you mean...

Comment: @Marcin the function make_classification from sklearn.datasets used in the code provides the data of the example

Comment: @Pranav Hosangadi I'd say its not that bad, for a DL question. Debugging was pretty straightforward. Also, it just worked, after I installed a few packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used wrong loss function, change this line

```
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

to, for example,

```
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='mse', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Categorical cross-entropy needs a one-hot encoded `y` which means, you have to have a `0` or a `1` for every class. MSE is just mean squared error, so it will work. But you might try some other losses as well.

your `y`:

```
[1,0,1]
```

one-hot encoded `y`:

```
[[0,1], [1,0], [0,1]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, changing the loss function makes the network to learn. What I don't understand is that the target variable is already 0 and 1, so I don't understand why it didn't with the loss function categorical_crossentropy.